# Perron-Frobenius theorem applied to fusion of anyons

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

Context: I have come across this problem in the theory of anyons described by unitary  braided tensor categories where the Frobenius-Perron dimension (quantum dimension) of a charge is significant for the charge being abelian or non-abelian.

The problem is the following: Given a matrix $N_a$ with only non-negative integer entries, the Perron- Frobenius theorem tells me that the eigenvalues of this matrix are bounded in absolute value by the Frobenius-Perron eigenvalue which I will call $d_a$. Now, given $d_a=1$, I want to proof that $$\sum_j (N_a)_{ij}=1$$ for all $i$. Together with the nonnegativity and the entries being integers, I deduce that this is equivalent to proving that the matrix has exactly one entry equal to 1 in every row and all the others equal to zero. In the [Wiki article on the Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Non-negative_matrices), I have seen the inequalities 
$$\min_i \sum_j(N_a)_{ij} \leq d_a \leq \max_i \sum_{ij} (N_a)_{ij} $$
but they do not seem to help me unfortunately.

**It is also know that the corresponding eigenvector to $d_a$ has only positive entries which given that $d_a=1$ implies the matrix non-singular**.
I know from other sources  that actually all elements of the eigenvector are even greater equal 1 but I would rather try to avoid using that if not needed. It might be needed however, if you think it is, please point out why.
**Furthermore, $N_a$ cannot have zero-columns, at least one element in every column must be non-zero**

Comment: Isn't $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ a counterexample?

Comment: It's rather hard to guess what might be useful without knowing anything about those "more properties".

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I forgot to put that the corresponding eigenvector is made up only of positive entries which prohibits your example, thx for pointing out. I think, it might be possible to show this now without further assumptions on $N_a$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I made some edits, I think it might be enough. At least on my paper, I  feel I am close.

Comment: @saulspatz of course, but I need that the row sums to 1, i.e. only one entry in the row is 1. How do you rule out that there is an entry bigger than one or non-zero multiple entries ?

Comment: Sorry, I was reading the question backwards.  Need more tea.

Comment: I think, it is still not enough, but I know additionally that the transpose of $N_a$ cannot have zero rows, i.e. non zero-columns are allowed for $N_a$

Comment: Do you know that the matrix is nonsingular?

Comment: Yes, I think it is. How does this help?

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, allow me to write your $N_a$ as $N$.

Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector for the Perron eigenvalue $1$ with strictly positive entries.
We have
$\sum_{j=1}^n N_{ij} v_j = v_i$ for each $i$.

Since the entries of $N$ are nonnegative integers, we must have $N_{ij} = 0$ if $v_j > v_i$.  Thus the only possible nonzero entries in column $j$ are in rows $i$ where 
$v_i \ge v_j$. Moreover if $v_j = v_i$ and $N_{ij} > 0$, the only possibility is $N_{ij} = 1$ and all other entries in row $i$ are $0$.

Now you say there are no $0$ columns.  Thus for each $j$ we have some $i$ with $v_i \ge v_j$ and $N_{ij} > 0$.  Define a mapping $f$ of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ to itself so that $f(j)$ is some $i$ with $N_{ij} > 0$ ; in case there is a choice, take one with the greatest $v_i$.  We have $v_{f(j)} \ge v_j$.

Now I claim $N_{ij} > 0$ only for $v_i = v_j$, so that $v_{f(j)} = v_j$.  Suppose this is not so.
 Take  $j$ with the greatest possible  $v_j$ for which $v_{f(j)} > v_i$. 
For $v_k > v_j$, $v_{f(k)} = v_k$, so $N_{f(k),k} = 1$ and all other entries in row $f(k)$ are $0$.  This says that $f(k) \ne f(k')$ for all $k' \ne k$:
the map $f$ is injective from $S = \{k: v_k > v_j\}$ to itself. Since $S$ is finite, $f$ must be surjective on $S$ as well.  In particular, $f(j) = f(k)$ for some $k$, but then it is impossible to have $N_{f(j),j} > 0$.

The conclusion is that $f$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, and $N$ is a permutation matrix.  This does indeed have all its row-sums $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like this is a very neat proof. I understand that you want to prove that $f$ is a permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ but I am not quite getting it in full. What if all $v_i$ are the same, then when I set up the map, taking the one with the greatest $v_i$ is ambiguous which could lead to the map not being injective. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: The point is that if $N_{k, j} = 1$ with $v_k = v_j$, all other entries in row $k$  must be $0$.  So you can have $k = f(j)$, but you can't have $k = f(j')$ for any other $j'$.  That says it is injective.

Comment: Right. Another doubt: How did you use that the $v_i$ are positive in this proof?

Comment: If some $v_k = 0$, you could make $N_{ik}$ arbitrary without affecting anything.

Comment: Is it possible, that in the second line of the penultimate paragraph you meant "for which $v_{f(j)}>v_j$"?  If I understand the full argument correctly now, you prove that $f$ is bijective on $S$ and then argue that $f(j)$ itself is in $f(S)$ so that you already now that there was some $k\in S$ so that $N_{f(j),k}=1$ which makes it impossible that $N_{f(j),j}$ is non-zero. Do I understand it?